# Angular 2, IE11, not loading styles when inspector is opened

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

The app launches fine, but no styles are loaded. Running in local machine. Works fine in chrome and firefox.

Also tested in https://www.browserstack.com/, there no styles are loaded when testing in edge.

Comment: Not much info available but try to add your site to trusted sites using Internet options > security. Usually fonts, JavaScript doesn't work when security is set as high. Give this a try.

Comment: can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Hmm, when I ng-build, it doesn't load it at all in IE11:
http://lrstudio.eu/stuff/dist/ and in EDGE 15, it doesn't load the styles